# com.common.api.ApiException: 8: The connection to Google Play services was lost

Tags: android

i have been trying to implement google sign in on an app using firebase but I get the above error always. When i create other android projects and try to include the google sign in, they work properly but this is an application from a client that needs to be updated. I have tried researching and even changing the dependencies versions but no success. Please help. 
 this is the error on my logcat
"06-21 17:51:34.323 7500-7520/com.Haas.CryptoActu2 E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)}"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to investigate into which HTTP request is being posted and what response you get

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect google sign in on the onfailure method then nothing happens and still facing this problem.

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply. i don't understand your comment. I first used my code, it worked on other applications except this one application. So i even decided to use the code on the google official documentation website and still noting happens

Comment: the error above is the exception that is returned when the sign in task is not successful. When i create other projects in the android studio, everything works fine including the google sign in. The problem is with only this application. I was sent the source code and i opened the template in my android studio but it doesn't work

Comment: am also getting this error on the logcat     "06-21 17:51:34.323 7500-7520/com.Haas.CryptoActu2 E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)}"

Comment: You also sure with your API Key ?

Comment: yes everything seems okay. But i have noticed that even though the project is configured in the firebase console, it is not able to write to the database and points out that the path to the database should be specified in the code. It is for this reason that i believe that the project is not configured correctly since if it was, at least it should have been able to access the firebase database. Let me investigate this issue and get back to you. Thanks